# Show item of object

Tags: php, class, object

I have this code in php:

```
try 
{ 
    $wsdl_url = 'https://url';
    $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url); 
    $return = $client->RecuperarDatos(); 
    print_r($return); 
}
```

Show this:

```
stdClass Object ( [RecuperarDatosResult] => stdClass Object ( [ItemCatalogo] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [descripcion] => NAME1 - (00001) [id] => 00001 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [descripcion] => NAME2 - (00002) [id] => 00002 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [descripcion] => NAME3 - (00003) [id] => 00003 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [descripcion] => NAME4 - (00004) [id] => 00004 ) 
...
```

how I can do to show only NAME1, NAME2, NAME3, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `print_r($return->RecuperarDatosResult->ItemCatalogo[0]->descripcion);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried that but it shows me only the first. I tried counting items ( then make a for ) with this  $qty = count($return->RecuperarDatosResult);  but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($return->RecuperarDatosResult->ItemCatalogo as $item) {
    echo $item->descripcion;
}
```